# Optional getopt function

Tags: c, getopt

I am having difficulty making getopt operation optional. Here's a part of my code. It takes in an argument file, which if it is there, it counts the number of characters. If not it counts the stdinput characters.

My question is what optarg gets set to once it is undeclared? And how do I go about making my option -c optional and making this work.

Currently it always read from stdin.

```
while( (option = getopt(argc, argv, "c::") ) != -1 ) {
  switch(option) {
  case 'c':
    if (optarg == NULL) {
        file = stdin;
      }
    else {
      file = fopen(optarg, "r");
    }
    while( (ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF ) {
      count++;
    }
    printf("%d %s\n", count, optarg);
    fclose(file);
    break;
```

Comment: "What `optarg` gets set to once it is undeclared"??? You couldn't be more unclear than that.

Comment: Why `::`, instead of `:`?

Comment: "Two colons mean an option takes an optional arg" - linuxmanual

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I am clarifying whether optarg get set to NULL when the option -c becomes optional. I think this might be why this is wrong because when I print optarg, it gives a Seg Fault

Comment: I wasn't aware of this GNU extension. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optional arguments to options are not supported by "Standard" (POSIX) [`getopt()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html). The use of a double colon `"::"` is a [GNU `getopt()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html) extension.

To have `getopt()` set `optarg` to an option's "optional" argument use the option on calling the program like this:

```
program -coptional_argument_to_option_c
```

---

However alternatively you might like to take one of the the following approaches:

- Define `-c filename` with *filename* being mandatory. And if `-c filename` misses just count what is read from `stdin`.
- Or define `-c` with no argument to tell your program **what to do** (to count here) and additionally define an option to tell your program **where to read from** like `-f filename`. If the latter misses read from `stdin`.

Comment: when filename argument is mandatory (c:), getopt() automatically indicate that the option needs an argument. So where do I place the conditional statement?

Comment: @Sarc: Which "*conditional statement*"?

Comment: Thank you, i got it working through the 1st alternative

Answer (score 1):

I found this in the getopt man pages:

> Two colons mean an option takes an optional arg; if there is text in the current argv-element (i.e., in the same word as the option name itself, for example, "-oarg"), then it is returned in optarg, otherwise optarg is set to zero.

http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt_long.

This page kinda explains it a bit better:

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=175771&seqNum=3

> Finally, if an option letter in optstring is followed by two colon characters, then that option is allowed to have an optional option argument. (Say that three times fast!) Such an argument is deemed to be present if it's in the same argv element as the option, and absent otherwise. In the case that it's absent, GNU getopt() returns the option letter and sets optarg to NULL. For example, given—

`while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "ab::")) != 1)
   ...`

> —for -bYANKEES, the return value is 'b', and optarg points to "YANKEES", while for -b or '-b YANKEES', the return value is still 'b' but optarg is set to NULL. In the latter case, "YANKEES" is a separate command-line argument.

Check if this also works for you.

Comment: Thank you, this short option syntax is fairly cryptic.